# Where condition in dynamodb rekognition.search_faces_by_image function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-rekognition

Hi I am getting database data in this code like this

```
response = rekognition.search_faces_by_image(
                        CollectionId='athlete_collection',
                        Image={'Bytes': image_crop_binary}
                    )
```

I have a column named `event` in `athlete_collection`  so I want to put a condition that just get data where  event = 'newevent'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you are going wrong concept-wise , because you are trying to filter **athlete_collection** which is just a **Rekognition collection** which just contains facial landmarks data of stored faces and face-ids corresponding to that faces , then you can use those face-ids to retrieve corresponding data like *names,address,etc* if and only if you stored such details in a database while indexing those faces in the collection , if in your use case **event name** is stored in database , so you have to filter data while retrieving results from database corresponding to results obtained from **search_faces_by_image** API

you can do this by following below example:

```
response = rekognition.search_faces_by_image(
    CollectionId='collection_name',
    Image={'Bytes':image_crop_binary}
    )

if len(response['FaceMatches']) > 0:
    # Return results
    for match in response['FaceMatches']:

        face = dynamodb.get_item(
        TableName='table_name',               
        Key={'RekognitionId': {'S': match['Face']['FaceId']}}
        )


    if 'Item' in face:
        event = face['Item']['event_name']['S']
        full = face['Item']['full_name']['S']

    if(event=='newevent'):
        #your code goes here , i.e what you want to do if event=="newevent"
```

Comment: can I pass a key in  get_item ?

Comment: You can't pass a key but you can apply a filter based on secondary indexes that will be 'eventname'